# Clarification on Wolfram Mathworld's explanation of the connection between Gelfand Transform and Fourier Transform

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, operator-algebras, convolution, banach-algebras

[image]

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GelfandTransform.html

In the definition, what does $x$, $\hat x(\phi)$, and $\phi$ represent exactly if we were to consider definition of the Fourier transform? Can someone please help make the connection between Gelfand transform and Fourier transform more explicit?

Where Fourier transform is taken to be the usual operator:
$$
\mathcal{F}(\omega) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathcal{f}(t) \, e^{-i\omega x} \, \mathrm{d} t
$$

If $\phi$ represents the transform itself, I cannot see how it would satisfy $\phi(xy) = \phi(x)\phi(y)$

Comment: If you are working on $L^{1}$ with multiplication equal to convolution, then the characters are point evaluations of the Fourier transform. That is, a character $\omega$ is $\omega(x)=\hat{x}(p)$ for some $p$.

Comment: Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis* has a very nice section on this, perhaps you can take a look. The fact is that $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ is a Banach algebra with *convolution* being the multiplication operation.